# Why does this code always pull from the database?

Tags: database, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

When I navigate to various pages, the database query is always executed, but I would expect it to be executed only the first time, then store the firstName in the session var.

```
 defp get_first_name(conn, %{email: email}) do
    firstName = if sessionFirstName = get_session(conn, :firstName) do
      # found firstName in the session conn variable
      sessionFirstName
    else
      user_record = EVALUsers.get_eval_user_by_email!(email)

      %{firstName: firstName} = user_record
      firstName
    end

    if firstName do
      conn
      |> assign(:firstName, firstName)
      |> put_session(:firstName, firstName)
    else
      conn
      |> assign(:firstName, email)
      |> put_session(:firstName, email)
    end
  end
```

Thanks in Advance!
Scott

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `=` is a match operator in Elixir, not an assignment operator. Note that your first `if` statement has the match operator, not a `==` conditional operator.

The first time your function is executed, `sessionFirstName` contains a `nil` value. The `get_session()` call also returns a `nil` value, since the `:firstName` key is not found in the session. Thus, the match operator in the first `if` finds a match, which causes the conditional to evaluate to `true`. That causes it to return the value of `sessionFirstName`, which is `nil`, and put it into the `firstName` variable. The last `if` statement finds that the value of `firstName` is `nil`, which is falsey, so it evaluates the `else` and stores the value of the `email` variable in the session.

The next time your function is executed, `sessionFirstName` again contains a `nil` value. The `if` statement compares the return value of the `get_session()` call (which should actually return a value this time) to the value of `sessionFirstName`, and finds that they do not match. This causes the `else` clause to be executed, and your database gets hit, and the returned value gets put into the session.  Henceforth, since the session returns a value but `sessionFirstName` contains a `nil`, the actions described in this paragraph get executed every time.

My suggestion would be to use a `cond` structure to test the various possibilities.

```
defp get_first_name(conn, %{email: email}) do
  firstName =
    cond do
      sessionFirstName = get_session(conn, :firstName) ->
        sessionFirstName
      %{firstName: firstName} = EVALUsers.get_eval_user_by_email!(email) ->
        firstName
      true ->
        email
    end

  conn
  |> assign(:firstName, firstName)
  |> put_session(:firstName, firstName)
end
```

Comment: Brian, thanks for your help.  It is an error to change the = to == in the first line, so I am confused as to what you are suggesting on how to correct the problem.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some suggested code modifications.